# Creating a binary image

Tags: matlab

```
clear all;
clc;
imag = imread('286502.png');
image_binary = im2bw(imag,0.85);   %converte image to binary
image_binary = not(image_binary);

figure(1);clf
imagesc(image_binary);colormap(gray)
```

I am using this code to genarate a binary image of an ellipse having its inside as white while outside as black.But , the problem i am facing is that whenever the foreground and background of my input ellipse is either light or dark then the binary image becomes all black or all white.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the gray-scale nature of our image, you may remove the line im2bw command because that flattens the gray-scale values into binary (0-1 or white/black).

if you just want to show a binary image in gray color, you can try customizing the colormap

```
colormap([0 0 0;0.5 0.5 0.5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`im2bw(imag,0.85)` thresholds at a fixed value, which will work for some images but not for others. I recommend that you binarize with a method such as Otsu, which determines an optimal threshold for each image individually.

```
image_binary = imbinarize(imag);
```